# Create report as both Crystal and Excel

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, oracle11g, business-objects, crystal-reports-xi

We have a report that queries Oracle and uses Crystal Reports to make a report.  The users would like the output as both a Crystal Report and Excel.  Yes, I know they can output the results of the report to Excel.  Is there any (reasonable) way to automatically provide both output formats?  The reports are run in Business Objects Enterprise.

I see the output format is set in the BOE Central Managament Console for the report under Schedule/Format.  That makes it look like the option is one or the other, not both.

Comment: BOE is pretty sparse on options... I'd be surprised if they allow the same report run to be exported in two different formats (just my guess, so don't lose hope just yet). Worst case scenario, you can just schedule two instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new publication and add this report, it will allow you to have both crystal report and excel formats on the email as attachments in BOE.  Hope this helps.

Regards
Tracey